# Bolzano Weierstrass theorem in Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I need to check the correctness of this statement:

Let $f_n : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions. Is there a subsequence $\lim_{k\to \infty}f_{n_k}(x)$ that converges almost everywhere?

I guess the statement is wrong but not easy to construct the example.

Comment: They're just measurable functions going from the reals to the reals. Hint: the range isn't compact, so the set of constant functions isn't compact.

Comment: In order to have an equivalent of the B-W theorem, you probably want that $\left\lvert f_n(x)\right\rvert\leqslant M$ for an $M$ independent of $n$ and $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The constant functions are measurable, so $f_n=n$ are measurable, but do not converge anywhere.